# iTunes Connect did not ask for bank or PayPal account when attempting to publish paid app in App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have just finished an app and sent some builds to iTunes Connect, but now I intend to send it to App Store for a price of, say, 1 USD.

I saw the 'Pricing and Availability' tab at iTunes Connect and it let me set the price of the app, so I set it 1 USD, no problems until now, but after that, in tab 'Prepare for Submission', there was no such thing as asking my bank or PayPal account.

How should I proceed? Should I submit for review anyway and this kind of information will be asked later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Agreements, Tax, and Banking** section to manage contracts with Apple, provide required financial information relating to iTunes developer payments and tax withholdings, and track the status of your iTunes agreements. If you plan to charge customers to download your apps, start with this section right away to request a contract for selling paid apps.

Apple publish the following documentation about adding your Banking details, [Setting Up Banking Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH21-SW17).